# Why does this apt-get command work in one context but not the other?

Tags: command-line, apt, docker

I'm trying to add the plpython package to my docker container (running an Ubunutu image) using the following command (RUN being the docker command that you can ignore if you don't know Docker):

`RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-plpython-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION`

However this gives the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-plpython-9.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-plpython-9.4'
INFO[0005] The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y postgresql-plpython-$PG_MA
JOR=$PG_VERSION] returned a non-zero code: 100
```

However if I insert this same command into [this part of an existing Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/e616341507a7beec3a161b0a366ba0d3400328fd/9.4/Dockerfile#L36) (i.e. I add the line `postgresql-plpython-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \`, the command works.

I don't know much about apt-get, so can someone explain why the package is found in the context of the parent Dockerfile, but not my Dockerfile? What can I do to get the package to be found?

Comment: I think you should modify the question to make it clearer that you are creating an image using the Postgres image as base image. In the last paragraph you use the term "parent Dockerfile", but before that you speak of an "Ubuntu image" and "an existing Dockerfile", so that's easy to miss.

Answer (score 5):

The Dockerfile of the base image has the following instruction:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

This clears the package lists downloaded by `apt-get update`. That's why you get the error. To solve this problem, execute `apt-get update` again in your Dockerfile.

Comment: That sounds like it could be right! I'll check it when I get the chance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bundle your update and install commands. See the official [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) on the matter. Docker has various issues with cache layer invalidation that can throw errors otherwise.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-plpython-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION
```

You can also silence install output, and clean up apt caches to minimize your image and cache size.

```
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
 && apt-get install -qqy \
 postgresql-plpython-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*
```